# How do you set the colour of the text of the prompt over an UISearchBar?

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

For instance, I want the text that sits on top of my SearchBar here to be white. The prompt is hardly readable right now.

[image: screenie]

Comment: It'd also be good to have a way of setting this colour without using `valueForKey:` for fear of app store rejection.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `titleTextAttributes` of the navigation bar? The title in the navigation bar would have the same issue as the prompt.

Comment: @rmaddy I just tried, but no cigar.  Setting the titleTextAttributes on the presenting view controller didn't change the text; trying to set it on the SearchController's navigationController.navigationBar doesn't work because it doesn't exist.